# Printing the Name of Dictionaries inside a Collection

Tags: vba, dictionary, collections

I have created a collection which consists of several dictionaries.
As I try to loop through the collection to print the names of the dictionaries, I get the following error message: 450 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property argument.

My code reads as follows:

First, create the individual dictionaries and add the data to them:

```
Dim Cows, Dogs, Goats As Object

Set Cows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Dogs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Goats = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

[...Load the dictionaries with the data...]

Once this is done, create the collection of dictionaries and start to loop through it to see the names of each dictionary (the result should give us "Cows, Dogs, Goats" in the immediate window):

```
Dim TotalAnimals As New Collection

    TotalAnimals.Add Cows
    TotalAnimals.Add Dogs
    TotalAnimals.Add Swans
```

Here lies the problem:

```
Dim AnimalType As Variant
        For Each AnimalType In TotalAnimals
        Debug.Print AnimalType
Next AnimalType
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I guess only the data and not the name of the added dictionary is saved in 'TotalAnimals'.

Comment: If you make `TotalAnimals` a Dictionary then you can use `TotalAnimals.Add "Cows", Cows` etc and then use `For each k in TotalAnimals: Debug.Print k, TotalAnimals(k).Count: Next k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called 'Reflection'.  Unfortunately, the VBA language does not have reflection so you cannot directly achieve what you want.

You could emulate what you want using a 'wrapper' class to allow a name to be associated with a specific dictionary.

The example below implements a simple wrapper class which allows the name to be set, but not changed, and exposes the scripting.dictionary via the Host property.

Class AnimalType

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Properties

    Name                    As String
    Host                    As Scripting.Dictionary

End Type

Private p                   As Properties


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set p.Host = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = p.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal ipName As String)

    If VBA.Len(p.Name) = 0 Then
    
        p.Name = ipName
        
    Else
    
        Err.Raise 17 ' Can't perform the requested action
        
    End If
    
End Property


Public Property Get Host() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Host = p.Host
End Property
```

Thus

```
Dim Cows, Dogs, Goats As Object

Set Cows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Dogs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Goats = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

would become

Edited 30 Jan 2020 to correct the code below

```
Dim Cows as AnimalType
Dim Dogs as AnimalType
Dim Goats as AnimalType


Set Cows = new AnimalType
Cows.name="Cows"
Set Dogs = New AnimalType
Dogs.Name="Dogs"
Set Goats = New AnimalType
Goats.Name="Goats"
```

and then

```
Dim myAnimalType As Variant
For Each myAnimalType In TotalAnimals
    Debug.Print myAnimalType.Name
Next
```

Comment: Thank you freeflow. Yours seems to be the simplest solution but I receive an error message when creating Cows.Name, Dogs.Name and Goats.Name. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: Yes.  Its because I'm stupid.  I've revised by answer to do the corrections to change the 'Createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")' to ' New AnimalType'

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much for solving this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please adapt your code in the next way. You can give to the dictionary a `Name` (in fact a `Collection` `key`) when add it to `Collection`:

```
Sub testDictNameInCollection()
     Dim Cows As Object, Dogs As Object, Goats As Object
     Dim TotalAnimals As New Collection, i As Long, arrK
     
     Set Cows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     Set Dogs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     Set Goats = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     
     'load here the dictionaries...

     TotalAnimals.Add Cows, "Cows"
     TotalAnimals.Add Dogs, "Dogs"
     TotalAnimals.Add Goats, "Goats"
     arrK = Array("Cows", "Dogs", "Goats")
     
     For i = 0 To UBound(arrK)
        Debug.Print TotalAnimals.item(arrK(i)).count
     Next i
     TotalAnimals.item("Cows").Add "Cow 1 ", "a lot of milk"
     Debug.Print TotalAnimals("Cows").Items()(TotalAnimals("Cows").count - 1) 'last item of the "Cow" dictionary
End Sub
```

Since `Scripting.Dictionary` does not expose a `Name` property, you can use a class able to wrap a name, in order to use the object **and** its name:

1. Copy the next code in a class and name it "AnimalClass":

```
Option Explicit

Private dictName As String
Private dict As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = dictName
End Property

Public Property Let obj(dic As Object)
    Set dict = dic
End Property

Public Property Let Name(strName As String)
    dictName = strName
End Property

Public Property Get obj() As Object
    Set obj = dict
End Property
```

2. Copy the next code in a standard module:

```
Sub testDictionaryName()
  Dim Cows As Object, Dogs As Object, Goats As Object, i As Long
  Dim TotalAnimals As New Collection, animT As AnimalClass
  
 Set animT = New AnimalClass
   Set Cows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   For i = 1 To 2: Cows(i) = "Cows " & i: Next i 'load the dictionary
   animT.obj = Cows: animT.Name = "Cows"
   TotalAnimals.Add animT  'add the class in Collection
   
 Set animT = New AnimalClass
   Set Dogs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   For i = 1 To 3: Dogs(i) = "Dog " & i: Next i
   animT.obj = Dogs: animT.Name = "Dogs"
   TotalAnimals.Add animT
 
 Set animT = New AnimalClass
   Set Goats = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   For i = 1 To 4: Goats(i) = "Goat " & i: Next i
   animT.obj = Goats: animT.Name = "Goats"
   TotalAnimals.Add animT
  
 Dim myAnimalType As Variant
 For Each myAnimalType In TotalAnimals
     Debug.Print myAnimalType.Name, myAnimalType.obj.count, myAnimalType.obj.Items()(myAnimalType.obj.count - 1)
 Next
End Sub
```